# Python CodeChef NZEC error

Tags: python-2.7

[Problem link](https://www.codechef.com/problems/NOTINCOM)

For this problem on codechef I am getting NZEC error for my python code. I new to python and I am not sure why I am getting this error.
The link to the problem is given or it can be also found under: practice -> beginner -> Nothing In Common

My Code is:

```
def count_c():
    m=int(raw_input())
    n=int(raw_input())
    a = list()
    b = list()
    for _ in range(m):
        a.append(int(raw_input()))
    for _ in range(n):
        b.append(int(raw_input()))
    return len(list(set(a)&set(b)))

t=int(raw_input())
for _ in range(t):
    print(count_c())
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is get m and n using separate input statements. Since you want space separated input, you might want to use:

```
m, n = raw_input().split(" ")
```

for taking multiple inputs, use a list instead of multiple variables.
For example, for accepting m values, use:

```
a = raw_input().split(" ")
```

'a' will be a list with whatever number of values in the line provided.